# Sorting Custom UIPicker's Data and displaying the result on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting

I have a `custom Picker` that has the **Priorities**: **Low**, **Medium** and **High**.

I have A `custom Table` on the `main_View` that has two labels: 1 the item name and the other item priority.

When the user selects a priority and inserts the required data he is navigated to the `main_View` where i fetch the **item name** and **item priority**.

I did achieve this but what i want is the items on the `main_View` should be arranged according to the priority they have i.e. **Highest**, **Medium** and then **Low**.

```
static NSString CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
RecordList *records = [tablecontentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil) 
{ 
    NSArray *xibPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
    for (id fileObjects in xibPath) 
    {
        cell = (CustomCell)fileObjects; 
    } 
} 
cell.itemName.text =records.toDoItem; 
cell.itemPriority.text = records.toDoPriority; 

return cell;
```

Comment: where is the screenshot ?

Comment: what do you use to store the information? can show some code of cellForRow:atIndexPath methode (fetching your information to fill the tableView)

Comment: @NishantTyagi IM not able to add image's since i don't have enough reputations.

Comment: @geo : I'l do that..BDW i've used CoreData for storing the data.

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    RecordList *records = [tablecontentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *xibPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        for (id fileObjects in xibPath) {
            cell = (CustomCell*)fileObjects;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    cell.itemName.text =records.toDoItem;
    cell.itemPriority.text = records.toDoPriority;
        
    return cell;

Comment: IM sorry if thats clumsy..

Comment: can you update your question with the code for better formatting and bundled information @MohammedNaveedShaikh ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *objMOC = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordList" inManagedObjectContext:objMOC]];
    tablecontentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[objMOC executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]];
    sortArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (RecordList *strH in tablecontentArray) {
        if ([strH.toDoPriority hasPrefix:@"H"]) {
            [sortArray addObject:strH];
        }
    }
    for (RecordList *strH in tablecontentArray) {
        if ([strH.toDoPriority hasPrefix:@"M"]) {
            [sortArray addObject:strH];
        }
    }for (RecordList *strH in tablecontentArray) {
        if ([strH.toDoPriority hasPrefix:@"L"]) {
            [sortArray addObject:strH];
        }
    }

    [homeTable reloadData];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return sortArray.count;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    RecordList *records = [sortArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *xibPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id fileObjects in xibPath) {
            cell = (CustomCell*)fileObjects;
        }

    }


      cell.itemName.text =records.toDoItem;
      cell.itemPriority.text = records.toDoPriority;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @geo : Hey buddy this worked just fine.Although this may not be an efficient way rather,but then suggest me a good one :)                    Good Day.

Answer (score 0):

if you use coreData, you can extend your `UITableView` by a `NSFetchedResultsController`

first add the delegate in the class that holds the `UITableView`

```
// MyClass.h
MyClass : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    // ...
}

// MyClass.m

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSError *error = nil;

    fetchedResultsController = nil;
    if( ![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error] )
    {
        // Log the error and/or do something with it
        abort();
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if( !fetchedResultsController )
    {
        // Create the fetch request for the entity.
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordList"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"toDoPriority" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"toDoItem" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
        [sortDescriptor1 release];
        [sortDescriptor2 release];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // add predicate if you need
        NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"do I need a predicate?", things];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                               cacheName:@"MyRecordsCache"];

        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        [aFetchedResultsController release];
        [fetchRequest release];
        [sortDescriptors release];
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

--

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    RecordList *records = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *xibPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CustomCell *)[xibPath objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.itemName.text =records.toDoItem;
    cell.itemPriority.text = records.toDoPriority;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Geo:Buddy this works fine for alphabetical order i.e. this gives me the result like High,Low and then Medium.Probably since 'H' comes before 'L' which in turn comes before 'M'.

Comment: it's not usual to use alphanumeric fields for priorities, but use rank like numeric systems ;) you need a senseful indicator, so why don't use an enum in your code and save it as number? :)

Comment: or if you realy need to let it alphanumeric, you have to do a small workaround. use arrays in array for indexPath.section and indexPath.row

Comment: hey 'Geo' I got the idea to it.I may not be able to indent it properly since i cannot answer my question before 24hrs(Thanx to StackOverflow) but this one is working just fine.Please do check it.

Comment: sortArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    for (RecordList *strH in tablecontentArray) {
        if ([strH.toDoPriority hasPrefix:@"H"]) {
            [sortArray addObject:strH];
        }
    }
and did the same for M and L. It worked.

Comment: Would you be comfortable sharing your e-Mail address i can send you a copy of it.Perhaps.

Comment: @MohammedNaveedShaikh you can update your question for the first with your solution. But I unterstood what you have done. If you feel fine with it then it's okay :) it's just the way I am doing this things. Don't see a reason to waste the option for easy automation :P